# How to write if statement for get_post_meta in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I'm trying to right an if statement for get_post_meta. I want to display the info if something is there, if there is nothing, don't display anything. Here is an example I am working with, with no luck.

```
if(get_post_meta()); echo '<a href="'.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'text', true).'">'; endif;
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made an error in the syntax. Use

```
if($condition): statements; endif;
              ^
```

instead of

```
if($condition); statements; endif;
              ^
```

So your code would be

```
if(get_post_meta()):
    echo '<a href="'.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'text', true).'">';
endif;
```

That's the [alternative syntax for control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php).
You can always use the standard one

```
if($conition) {
    // statements
    // .....
}
else { 
    // otherweise
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That works perfect. I do know of the other way I saw this way and thought it would be cleaner for what I am doing. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Yes, that's only advantage, I'll give you that - looks cleaner - especially when it's mixed with HTML code.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that the $post_id argument of get_post_meta() is required, so calling it without arguments won't do much good. I'd recommend just calling it once, and store the return value for use both with the if statement and possibly subsequent output.